# overwhelmed with old beautiful experiences?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the feeling you have of old beautiful memories and experiences. You are feeling it as you say it.
Like saying for instance, I am enraptured (at this moment). What I want to say is that (I am overwhelmed with the old beautiful memories now as I speak/as I write).

The memories have to be beautiful not gloomy.

Comment: You may be describing **nostalgia**.

Answer (score 1):

To me 'nostalgia' has about it a kind of sadness--sadness because it is lost in the past, sadness because I cast a longing,lingering look behind to get those days back. It is nothing derogatory, but it is a sad word.

What I suggest is: REMINISCENCE(S)
The dictionary defines it an act of remembering long past experiences, often fondly / a mental image thus remembered.

However, one can further sweeten it with attributes like, 'fond', 'sweet' or 'pleasant'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really clear on what OP is looking for, so I'll offer two suggestions and hope one is fitting.

---

> [**relived**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relive)
>   *verb*: to experience (something) again in your imagination; to remember (something) so clearly that the same emotions you felt in the past are felt again. (Merriam-Webster *online*)

---

> [**imbued**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=imbued+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=imbued+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l3j0i22i30j0i22i10i30.0.0.0.8124...........0.GC2-OE9HBUg&gws_rd=ssl) *verb*: inspire or *permeate* with a feeling or quality.
>    "the entire performance was *imbued* with sparkle and élan"
>
> *synonyms*: permeate, saturate, diffuse, suffuse, pervade

(Google)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, ***nostalgia*** is [defined](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nostalgia) in part as:

> a sentimental yearning for the happiness of a former place or time

...which comes very close to what you seem to be after.